# Having no luck with data NASM

Tags: x86, nasm, dos

```
section .data

map db 1

section .text

start:
cmp byte [map], 1
je exit
jmp start

exit:
ret
```

I'm having no luck reading data. What I mean is that I assemble to the binary dos COM format and when I start it it just freezes. Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: For starters, you're issuing `ret` when there's nothing to `ret` to.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar, if memory serves correctly, DOS prepared the stack such that a `ret` at the end of the program would return control to COMMAND.COM. However, I don't have at hand my reference source of choice for this [Peter Norton's Programmers Guide to the IBM PC].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DOS com files are expected to be loaded at address 0x100. You should include line `org 0x100` at the start of your code.

Comment: Never knew that! Thanks!

Comment: @Gip-Gip, look up PSP ("Program Segment Prefix") to find out why this is the case. The short version is that DOS fills-in the first 0xff bytes of the segment with a bunch of information your program might need.